# How to make an opacity transition start from its current state, even if it's currently being affected by a transition?

Tags: css, image, animation, transition, fade

I'm creating a slideshow gallery where I want the images to fade in and out when the user presses the next or previous button.

I've gotten this to work using transitions to fade out the old image (image x) and fade in the new image (image y) over a 3 second duration. However, if I spam the next/previous button the new image (image y, that is fading in) will jump from whatever opacity it's at to 100% immediately before fading out.

My question therefore is how do I stop the new image (image y) jumping up to opacity 100% and instead just fade out from its current opacity as the "new new" image (image z) fades in?

Here is my CSS:

```
.mySlides{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
}


.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Then I just have some JS to add or remove the .fade class to the .mySlides element to make it fade in or out:

```
slides[new_slideIndex].classList.add("fade");
slides[current_slideIndex].classList.remove("fade");
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: share the code to debug

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I've just added my code for you

Comment: There isn’t a trivial way to handle this. Maybe https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/ can give you a few pointers.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I am assuming you are removing the `fade` class of image y before it actually transitions-in causing the error.

You could `setTimeout(function() {slides[current_slideIndex].classList.remove("fade")} , 3000)` to make sure it is removed after 3 seconds (completing transition) but I am not sure how the results would be and cannot try it out since I don't have all the necessary code - though I believe it could work

Another way would be to prevent the spam, by adding a `pointer-events:none` property to the next button on click and removing it with a `setTimeout` 3 seconds later, so that the next button can only be clicked once every 3 seconds ?

Comment: I think I might've confused you a bit; the image takes 3 seconds to fade in when it's loaded and 3 seconds to fade out when it's unloaded. At 1 second fade in the image is at 33% opacity, if the button is clicked at this time then it currently jumps from 33% to 100% opacity immediately and then fades out for 3 seconds. What I'd like it to do instead is: retain it's value of 33% and fade out for 3 seconds from 33% to 0%. Hopefully that makes a bit more sense? Thank you for your help though!